# How to enable CORS in Go

Tags: go, cors

I'm new to this CORS stuff in golang. I use this package "github.com/rs/cors". I tested it with the example code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
    "github.com/rs/cors"
)

func Hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Write([]byte("{\"hello\": \"world\"}"))
}

func main() {
    router := httprouter.New()
    router.GET("/", Hello)

    _cors := cors.Options{
        AllowedMethods: []string{"POST", "OPTIONS"},
        AllowedOrigins: []string{"http://localhost:8080"},
    }
    handler := cors.New(_cors).Handler(router)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8282", handler)
}
```

When I hit from the browser, it responses normally without any issue. When I hit from client made in Go, same thing happen. What do I miss?

Edit:
I expect that this CORS will filter request coming from different origin/server. When I put the allowed method to POST and OPTIONS only, and I hit with GET from browser and client made in Go, should it be returning error since GET is not allowed?, How to work with this package?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Your question is not clear, you wrote that it works okay on both the browser and the go client. Do you expect the code to fail? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Why do you expect something different to happen?

Comment: @Z.Kosanovic I updated the question please check thanks.

Comment: You have misunderstanding of CORS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS

Comment: CORS is meant for browsers to filter requests, so your Go server won't filter anything, and the Go client will ignore them (because it's not a browser and not retrieving resources in a way that is relevant to CORS).

Comment: For your `Go` client requests to be affected by CORS the client should be a web application running on a browser and it should be running on a different origin i.e a different (domain, protocol, or port) from the origin of the server it is making the requests to. Your browser `GET` request which i assume you are making via the browser's address bar is not a cross-origin HTTP request and therefore not affected by CORS either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CORS is a mechanism to prevent a script(i.e. Javascript) running in browser coming from different origin(server) calling to a specific server. This specific server need to be careful of any script hitting itself because some malicious things or any authorization policy might applied. This specific server can create a middleware in its APIs to check an  preflight request, a CORS request using OPTIONS method with some specific headers it carry.

Preflight request is a component of CORS model where this is part of CORS mechanism standarization applied to browsers. So the one who sent this preflight requests are browsers if any scripts executed via browser(do not mistaking it with hitting from browser address bar). This preflight request applied to APIs that usually execute requests like in Javascript you have XMLHttpRequest or Fetch APIs. Any kind of request with any method sent through these APIs will be preceded by separated request called "preflight" request using OPTIONS method bringing additional headers detailing the information of the caller. This preflight request will be handled by the destination server by checking its request headers and comparing with its CORS regulation applied. This Options will return the information of what method, origins(allowed origins), or any headers allowed based on its rule. Once this preflight request finish and get response with detailed of headers containing information of destination server cors policy. If the caller didn't violate anything based on that server cors policy, then the API/browser will make next request after that preflight request which is the actual request. Otherwise will return as cors error and actual request will never be made.

Calling from browser address bar wont have any effect since you're not  executing any script(from browser) and the browser address bar is usually a GET method, not OPTIONS method, hence won't be treated as preflight request. If you call it from client made in other programming language(e.g. Go), then CORS mechanism not applied here, because like other said cors applied to the calling from scripts in browsers. If you want to filter request from client other than browser(e.g. Go) from different server then what you need is OAUTH mechanism or ACL(Access Control List) which are different and have nothing to do with this CORS stuff.

Relating to the package you referred, that package is to ease your work so you dont have to handle the additional headers and preflight request yourself, instead you can wrap your handlers inside the package.

More about CORS [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: _CORS is a mechanism to prevent a script(i.e. Javascript) running in browser coming from different origin(server) calling to a specific server._ Absolutely not. CORS relaxes restrictions; it doesn't block anything.

Comment: _Any kind of request with any method sent through [the XMLHttpRequest or Fetch APIs] will be preceded by separated request called "preflight" request_. No; consider so-called [_simple_requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests).

Answer (score 4):

In my projects i always use a handler to set CORS and works very well.

```
func CORS(next http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
  return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
    w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization, accept, origin, Cache-Control, X-Requested-With")
    w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE")

    if r.Method == "OPTIONS" {
        http.Error(w, "No Content", http.StatusNoContent)
        return
    }

    next(w, r)
  }
}
```

In this code block you can see the headers setting permission for other sources, this can make your resources accessible from other domains.

A way to use this, if are you using the standard HTTP library, its like a middleware:

```
func mainHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){ ... }

http.HandleFunc("/",
    CORS(mainHandler),
)
```

Comment: Have you ever used github.com/rs/cors ?, Do I need to specify those response headers if I already specify them in my cors settings using the package?